# Is it possible to automatically exit full-screen mode in Safari on cmd-tab press?

Tags: macos, safari, fullscreen

I have a problem that while watching videos in Safari in full-screen, I need to access another program, but at the same time keep watching the video, in not-full-screen mode though. Currently if I cmd-tab from full-screen of Safari to another program, that covers only a part of the screen,
I get this in my Safari window:
[image]

**How can I switch to non-full-screen move automatically after using the combination of alt+tab?

Or is there any alternative that could be tailored to my need?**

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your problem, when you are in full screen video, you can switch to normal video size by <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>

(And switch between Apps by <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>, not <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>)

Comment: Not exactly. I am looking for a combination of these two commands. And the part with alt+tab in my question was a typo, I meant cmd+tab.